# Is it legal to walk out of school, unexcused in Colorado

Tags: education, minor, colorado

There are several school walkouts coming up in Colorado and nationwide that I plan to participate in, most likely without my parent's permission/knowledge. I am 16. Is this legal?

Comment: What is truancy?

Comment: Usually you have to miss a certain number of days within a time period to be considered "truant" by the law. You'd be better off just asking the school. State laws often just set bare minimim requirements that school districts must act on, but some districts may be even more strict than the state law in handling truant students and what they'd do to punish them (e.g. they may give you detention or somehow force you to make up the day etc).

Comment: Just wondering, why the downvotes? I don't really have much more to say here, I feel if I add anything it would just be pointless text. Did I leave out anything important?

Comment: @tbfninja if you have education policy at the county or city level, you should include that.

Comment: @Stackstuck I don't know of any policy, I was hoping to learn of it.

Comment: Also dheck https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/students-free-speech-rights-public-schools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the relevant cases is [Tinker vs. Des Moines](https://www.aclu.org/other/tinker-v-des-moines-landmark-supreme-court-ruling-behalf-student-expression).

In it, students wore black armbands in protest, and were suspended from school unless they agreed to remove the armbands.  Because their protest was non-disruptive, the school's position was found to be a violation of their civil rights.  Generally, the school cannot interfere with students' rights to free speech and civil liberties.   That does not mean that students are free from discipline however.

If students walk out, whether in protest of a great injustice, or just to get lunch, or go to a concert, the school can discipline the student for walking out.

What the school ***cannot*** do, however, is treat the reason for the walkout differently.   They cannot give minor detention for one reason (say, a rock concert), and a full suspension for politically motivated walk-out.

If they are dispensing harsher punishments based on the *reason* for the walkout, that is crossing a big line.

More detailed discussion can be found at http://time.com/5171160/gun-control-student-protest-history/

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but it does provide useful data.